# lm function is giving a warning that it is dropping rows

Tags: r, lm

This is my question

Do the developers that make more games charge higher prices?

my code:

```
dev_data <- steam_data_final %>% 
  group_by(developer) %>% 
  summarize(num_dev = n(), avg_price = mean(price, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(num_dev))
dev_data
```

but this model isn't working, getting Warning: Dropping 3038 rows with missing values

```
mod_dev <- lm(num_dev ~ avg_price, data = dev_data)
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data with dput for example

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any `NA` using `summary()` or `is.na()` for each column. If you do have any `NA`, then it is the reason why the `lm()` gives you the warning message.

Also, it seems like you need to use `lm(avg_price ~ num_dev, data = dev_data)` instead of `lm(num_dev ~ avg_price, data = dev_data)`. It seems like the dependent variable should be `avg_price`, not `num_dev`. (It depends on your question of research.)

Comment: Yes I figured it out, thank you so much!!